# How to write hard ILP problem?

Tags: integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I want to write/create hard ILP problems. When I say hard I mean the question should be solvable in at least 20 minutes with non-commercial ILP solvers. Can someone show me a direction or know how to create these problems?

Comment: There are a few examples of NP hard problems that can be written as ILP here: http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Nicolas.Nisse/lectures/7IntegerLP.pdf

Comment: Take pretty much any ILP model (vehicle routing, shop scheduling, ...) and scale it up or down until the run time is within your target window.

Comment: Problem is eventually I want to make this task automated. So even though I select a problem and transform it to ILP it doesn't really solve my real problem. But thanks for the answers I'll definitely check it and going try find a pattern.